# How to return string[] instead of Observable<string[]> in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

my question is very simple:

Consider the following angular method... this method returns a list of ids of firebase documents:

```
private getAllOrdersIds(){
    return this.ordersCollection.snapshotChanges()
    .map(changes =>{
      return changes.map(a=>{
        return a.payload.doc.id;
      });
    });
  }
```

the previous method, returns an object of type `Observable<string[]>`, but
I need to return `string[]`, (not observable)

How can I do this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You must subscribe to the Observable to get the result, which will be of type `string[]`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan what happens is that this method is used by another method that also uses an observable, my intention is to cut the chain of observables ...

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511) to see several ways to combine observables.

Answer (score 0):

I see you need to combine several observables. You can't break the observable chain. You need to transform your stream instead. For this, use mergeMap:

```
const data$: Observable<any> = this.getAllOrdersIds().pipe(
    mergeMap((orderIds: string[]) => this.otherMethodReturningObservable(orderIds))
);

data$.subscribe(data => {
    // do something with combined data...
});
```